# Octave - Merging matrix by columns without looping

Tags: matlab, matrix, merge, octave

I would like to merge a table on Octave without looping. Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
column1 column2 column3 
1        1       1
1        2       2
1        1       2
1        1       3
2        1       3
2        1       1
```

to like this:

```
column1 column2 column3 
1        1       6
1        2       2
2        1       4
```

I tried to do it with looping but it's really too slow. Is there a function that can do it without looping ?

Comment: I can't see a system here and you should really describe how you want to "merge" them. And show your code with the for loop which does what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of `unique` and `accumarray`:

```
A = [1        1       1
     1        2       2
     1        1       2
     1        1       3
     2        1       3
     2        1       1];


[U,~,ind] = unique(A(:,1:2),'rows'); %get the unique rows based on the column 1 and 2.
AC        = accumarray(ind,A(:,3)); %sum the value of column 3 based on column 1 and 2
M         = [U,AC] % creation of the final matrix.
```

**Result:**

```
M =

   1   1   6
   1   2   2
   2   1   4
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this is exactly what I want to do. Thanks.